# How do I get Burbon Neat running with code kit?

Tags: codekit, neat

I have a burbon running on code kit.  It is not problem, I cant get neat running?

when i put

```
@import "neat";
```

I get this error

Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: neat.
              Load paths:
                /
                /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/bourbon/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets
        on line 13 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.wordpress/wp-content/themes/blankslate/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

Since CodeKit version 1.8, Neat is built in. You don't need to install anything, just write this in your SASS/SCSS file:

```
@import "bourbon", "neat";
```

Comment: (this imports both Bourbon and Neat - the former is required for the latter)

Comment: Where does this import to? I cannot see this imported to my compiled style.css - Thanks

Comment: @raison I don't think they are imported into the CSS, but are accessible to your SASS file, because they are mixins, not classes. If this does not throw any errors by your compiler, then your import is successful. Try writing ".myClass {@include linear-gradient(to top, red, orange);}" in your SASS file and see what gets rendered into your CSS.

Comment: aha - that makes sense and is a neat way of managing it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just a note - should be `@import "bourbon", "neat";`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 'Neat' folder is inside your stylesheets folder and use @import "neat/neat";

directory example:

[sitename] > [assets] > [css] > styles.css, [sass] > _main.sass, styles.sass, [neat]

Answer (score 0):

Neat is a framework on top of Bourbon, so it does not automaticaly come with Bourbon.
Install Neat as following.

In Terminal:

```
gem install neat
```

Then cd to your Sass directory and run:

```
neat install
```

In your Sass file:

```
@import "neat/neat";
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to do:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
```

before:

```
@import "neat/neat";
```

so your final scss file should start with(in the same order):

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon"; 
@import "neat/neat";
```